# Rspec VerifyingDouble object_double wrong number of arguments

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I have a class:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(foo, bar)
  end
end
```

and I'm trying to create a verifying double like this:

```
object_double(SomeClass.new)
```

This gives me the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

How do I prevent this?

I tried doing it like this also, even though it doesn't make much sense to me

```
object_double(SomeClass.new, initialize: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SomeClass#initialize` method requires 2 arguments.  You are calling `SomeClass.new` with no arguments.  Ruby raises an `ArgumentError` in these circumstances.  You need to either pass 2 arguments to `SomeClass.new`, change your `initialize` definition to be tolerant of no arguments being passed, or use a different kind of RSpec verifying double that doesn't require you to create an actual `SomeClass` instance.  For example, you could use `instance_double(SomeClass)`.